# Accepting "Share as attachment" functionality as a Mac email client

Tags: macos, cocoa, email, email-client

I'm trying to make a super-simple "email client" to accept the in-app functionality of sending a file/document as an email attachment. I don't need any other email functionality at the moment (I will be passing the data onto gmail api calls to draft a message on webmail), all I need is for the application to be seen as a valid email app and to accept the system calls for sending an email attachment.

So far I've found that I can configure the Mail.app preferences to use a different email app as long as it's compiled (from Xcode, as opposed to an AppleScript app), but I have not been able to get any test apps to play nice with the Share/send functionality from other applications. This menu item is grayed out, or throws an error ("The SendMail doesn't know how to talk to your default mail client. Please select a different mail application to use.") unless I am configured to use Mail or Outlook as my email client in which case it works fine.

What would be needed to accept these system calls for email sending? I just need to grab the data sent, and handle it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your client app must register itself for `mailto` URL scheme. Add this to your Info.plist:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>mailto: urls</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>mailto</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

It needs to handle the event. This can be a start:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [appleEventManager setEventHandler:self
                           andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                         forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
                            andEventID:kAEGetURL];
}

- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString *link = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    /* do something with the link */
}
```

It's not clear [for me] how you will send the attachment. Share > Email in the Finder?
In any case, you may need to add something to handle attachments.

Comment: Thanks, djromero. Would this work for in-app menu functionality? (like sending/sharing via email from Word or Adobe Reader), or is this only for URL-clicked email requests?

Comment: It's global, I think. At least it works in any place where I can send an email (I don't have Word or Adobe reader). You can configure it in Mail.app prefs -> General.

Comment: I've gotten closer, but still nothing close to what I need yet. The code above handles Mailto links from a browser href click, but not for the "Attach to email" app actions. Generally it appears that it fires off a series of apple events to trigger this behavior from within the app, but these events do not fire if it figures the app is incapable of handling the event. It knows this ahead of time, however, so I am unsure if it's a plist entry or what. Still looking. Interestingly, even Thunderbird has this limitation, and their forums mention MAPI integration issues as the suspected root cause.